# Which arena do I get cards from a when opening a Chest

Tags: clash-royale

I'm currently in Arena 4, hovering around 1300 trophies. I just played a match in Arena 5 and won, therefore giving me a Magical Chest. If I opened up this magical chest in Arena 4, would it still give me cards from Arena 5 since the chest is from Arena 5? Or would it give me cards from Arena 4 and lower because I opened up the chest in Arena 4?

Answer (score 1):

It has the potential to give you Arena 5 cards. The chests keep the level where they were won. You should see a "level 5" on your magical chest. Congrats!

Note, you aren't guaranteed to get an arena 5 card, but it is possible.